# Backslash + number interpreted by PHP as an octal value, how to block this?

Tags: php, octal

I have to reformat a string that can contain the following :

```
$string = "---8\7----";
```

The problem is that '\7' is interpreted by PHP as an octal value instead of just '\' and then '7'.

How can I block php from doing this please ? Of course, I need to keep the '\'
Thanks.

Comment: How are you getting the input?  From a file?  From a HTML form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, escape the backslash with another backslash, but I feel I should mention why this happen. Your string is written with double quote marks, which in PHP enters into [template mode where certain rules gets invoked](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing), and one of them are indeed what you've stumbled upon. Using single quotes fixes this also, by it not doing any templating ;

```
$string = '---8\7----';
```

It's the pro's and con's of the two modes, really, but as long as you're aware of this, it shouldn't bite you too hard in the future. :)

Comment: Replacing the double quotes by single quotes did the trick !
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You need to give Backslash for escaping that charatcer.

```
$string = "---8\\7----";
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the backslash.

```
$string = "---8\\7----";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two slashes:

```
$string = "---8\\7----";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use escape char:

```
$string = "---8\\7----";
```